# Directional Derivative along A Curve

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find the directional derivative of $f(x,y,z) = x^2yz^3$ along the curve with parametric equations $$\begin{align}x & = e^{-t}, \\ y & = 1 + 2 \sin t, \\ z & = t - \cos t, \end{align}$$ at the point $P$ where $t = 0$.

I know how to find the directional derivative along a vector, but how I can I find it along this curve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means, along the *tangent* vector to the curve.

There is a very simple way to do this: substitute $x,y,z$ with the coordinates of the curve, getting:
$$
F(t) = f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) = f(e^{-t}, 1+2\sin t, t-\cos t) = ...
$$

Now simply take the derivative with respect to $t$!

**EDIT** Otherwise, take the scalar product between the gradient of $f$, and the tangent vector to the curve at $t=0$.

The tangent vector to the curve is the vector:
$$
v= \bigg(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt}\bigg),
$$

so in our case, $(-e^{-t},etc.)$.

If your book (or professor) want you to take a *unit* tangent vector, divide this by the norm (but I don't think you have to do it, along the *curve*...ask your teacher).

The gradient is:
$$
\nabla f = \bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\bigg),
$$

so in our case, $(2xyz^3,etc.)$.

Now take the scalar product of these two vectors, at $t=0$. Which means at the coordinates $(x(0),y(0),z(0))= (1,etc.)$

Comment: Don't forget to divide by the norm of $grad (e^{-t},1+2\sin t,t-\cos t)$ with respect to $t$.

Comment: Yes, especially if you want the *unit* tangent vector. Check in your book if you need to normalize or not, or ask your teacher!

Comment: Is there an easier way to do it? Substituting with the parametric equations in f and then differentiating will be very long.

Comment: @Michael why should I divide by the norm of grad(e−t,1+2sint,t−cost) with respect to t ?

Comment: @Abdul3333 Otherwise, it is the scalar product of the tangent vector and the gradient. But the calculations are pretty much the same...

Comment: Please explain more... I feel like an idiot today :/

Comment: Also, how to calculate the norm of the gradient exactly?

Comment: Wait, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Now it is crystal clear, thank you very much!

Comment: @Abdul3333: let's consider a couple of smaller examples. Example 1: "take a derivative of $f(x)=x^3$ along the curve $x=t$. Example 2: "take a derivative of $f(x)=x^3$ along the curve $x=2t$. Notice that functions are identical and that the "curves", although parametrized differently, coincide. If you **dont** normalize tangent vector you get different directional derivatives: $3x^2$ and $6x^2$ respectively, which geometrically makes no sense because directional derivative of a function should depend **only** on the function and direction. Dividing by the norm of the gradient resolves that.